# How can I preserve a Windows 8 recovery partition if the drive uses GPT?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, gpt

I have a new Samsung ATIV book 9 with Windows 8 Professional, but I need to downgrade it to Windows 7. I want to keep the option to restore the Windows 8 on there, though.

The problem is that the drive is partitioned using GPT, and the Windows installer complains that it can't install on that drive due to that.

How can I preserve the recovery partition *and* install Windows 7 on that drive?

Comment: You have to create a bootable disk that supports UEFI ( and contained the required EFI files to do so ).  Windows 7 fully supports GPT and UEFI.  Lets start with the basics do you have `Secure Boot` disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, secure boot is disabled. I also just read that it should work, so now I only have to find out how to convert by Win7 USB drive to UEFI

Comment: @Ramhound is definitely pointing you in the right direction.  The only other gotcha to watch out for is that only 64-bit versions of Windows can boot from GPT (if the system has UEFI)